# Python variable length 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays

Today is my first day learning Python and have a question about 2-dimensional arrays. I need to create a 2 dimensional array but don't know the size of each of them. Is there something similar to the arraylist like in Java? Here's my code so you can see what I mean. It's for day 3 of last year's Advent of Code. So I guess a slight spoiler ahead if you haven't done it and want to see the way I'm thinking of setting it up.

```
f=open('directions.txt')
houses = [0][0]
rows = 0
column = 0
total = 0
for line in f:
    for c in line:
         if (str(c) == '^'):
        rows += 1
        houses[rows][column] += 1
    elif (str(c) == '>'):
        column += 1
        houses[rows][column] +=1
    elif (str(c)=='<'):
        column -= 1
        houses[rows][column-=1] +=1
    else:
        rows -= 1
        houses[rows][column] +=1
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you probably don't want `houses[row+=1] ... `.  Ie. take the equals sign out.

Comment: I'm using the row and column variables to keep track of the current row and column. How would I increment it?

Comment: If you want to increment `rows`, then do that on its own line ... `rows += 1` and then just do ... `houses[rows][ ... `

Comment: `houses = [0][0]` probably isn't what you want.  That is the same as `houses = 0`.  The reason is that `[0]` is a list with 0 as its one element and the second `[0]` says to take the first element of that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this

```
houses = dict()
rows = 0
column = 0
total = 0
for line in f:
    for c in line:
        houses.setdefault(rows,dict())
        houses[rows].setdefault(column, 0)
        if (str(c) == '^'):
            houses[rows][column] += 1
            rows += 1
        elif (str(c) == '>'):
            houses[rows][column] +=1
            column += 1
        elif (str(c)=='<'):
            houses[rows][column] +=1
            column -= 1
        else:
            houses[rows][column] +=1
            rows -= 1
```